# Find series that converge to $f(x) =\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Given $e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} $for all $x$ the convergence is uniform on every finite interval. Find series that converge to $$f(x) =\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$$ for all x.

My understanding is that I have to use the following theorem

> > Theorem : Suppose that ${F_n}$ converges uniformly to $F$ on $S = [a,b]$. Asumme that $F$ and all $F_n$ are integrable on [a,b], Then $$\int_a^b F(x) \, dx = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b F_n(x) \, dx$$

$$\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$$ $$ =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \int_0^x t^{2n} \, dt$$
 $$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \left[ \frac{t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right]_0^x $$ $$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}   $$

Is this the right theorem to refer to? Is this only what needs to be done to answer the original question?

Thx for your input

Answer (score 1):

I would use that theorem and also another that says power series converge uniformly on sets that are bounded away from the boundaries of the region of convergence. For this particular series, the radius of convergence is infinite, so that means it converges uniformly on all bounded sets. The interval $[0,x]$ is a bounded set.

(This series does not converge uniformly on its whole region of convergence, and the same is true of many power series, so the part about being bounded away from the boundary matters.)